# Java swing simple animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, random

i'm having trouble with a simple animation program(and yes this is homework). The question asks us to create a 100 objects of Particle class at random on a 500X500 window and move them around using a swing timer. Here's the problem i'm having, the particles being created don't appear to be random but they align along a diagonal axis, i'm having trouble finding the logic error, would really appreciate your help. Here's a screenshot that should make it clear. http://i57.tinypic.com/qswbix.jpg

I'm also posting the homework question at the end of the post in case anyone found my questions hard to understand. THank you for help

```
public class ParticleFieldWithTimer extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<Particle> particle = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    Timer timer; 
    boolean b; 
      public ParticleFieldWithTimer (){
       this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));


    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
        particle.add(new Particle());
    }


    timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            for (Particle p : particle) {                   
                p.move();                   
            }
            repaint();              
            }           
    });
    timer.start();  

}
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);

        for (Particle p : particle) {
        double temp1 = p.getX();
        double temp2 = p.getX();
        int tempX = (int) temp1;
        int tempY = (int) temp2;
        g2.fillRect(tempX, tempY, 3, 3);
        }           

    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("ParticleField");
        final ParticleFieldWithTimer bb = new ParticleFieldWithTimer();
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.add(bb);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                try {
                    bb.finalize();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                f.dispose();
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Here's the particle class

```
 public class Particle {
private int x , y ;

Random r = new Random();

public Particle () {

    x = r.nextInt(500);
    y = r.nextInt(500);

}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void move() {

    x += r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : - 1;
    y += r.nextBoolean() ? 1 : - 1;
    System.out.println("x : " + x+" y: " + y);
}



 }
```

> Create a class Particle that has two double fields x and y, a
>   constructor that initializes these fields to random values between 0
>   and 500, methods getX and getY that return their values, and a method
>   void move() that randomly adds or subtracts one to each of the values
>   of x and y. (The quantities added to x and y are two separate random
>   numbers.) Next, create a class ParticleFieldWithTimer that extends
>   JPanel. This class should prefer to be 500 * 500 pixels in size. Its
>   constructor should first fill an ArrayList field with 100
>   Particle objects, then start a Swing Timer that ticks 25 times a
>   second. At each tick, the action listener should first call the method
>   move for each particle, and then call repaint. The paintComponent
>   method of ParticleFieldWithTimer should draw each particle as a 3*3
>   rectangle to its current coordinates.

Comment: simple bug in your code, that's all.

Comment: You can also use `g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY(), 3, 3));` for the same result without all that fiddle casting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `paintComponent` method,

Replace

```
double temp2 = p.getX();
```

with

```
double temp2 = p.getY();
```

Good luck.

Comment: It's just a difficult to find typo... no need to feel like an idiot. :)

Comment: @user3363135, Also, since your getX() and getY() methods return int values why do you first assign them to double variables?

Comment: oh, x and y were actually supposed to be doubles and getX() and getY() were supposed to return doubles in the question, i just changed them during debugging to int to make sure that there was not a logic error in trying to convert a r.nextDouble() into a value between 0 and 500